# Not receiving any data in Kibana from Elasticsearch/Logstash. ELK Stack made in docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to build my first ELK Stack in Docker for a school project.

The goal is to have an ElasticSearch container along with it's volume.
A LogStash container linked to ElasticSearch along with it's volume aswell.
A Filebeat container to send data to LogStash
And finaly a Kibana Container to visualise the logs.

The problem I'm having is that even though all seems to be configured and working, Kibana isn't receiving anything from ElasticSearch. When I try to add a new index pattern I'm faced with this message : "No data streams, indices, or index aliases match your index pattern."
And not a thing is visible in Index Management.

Here's the **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
    Elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:8.5.3
        container_name: elasticsearch
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - elastic_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
        environment:
            ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx750m -Xms750m"
            discovery.type: single-node
            xpack.security.enabled: false
        ports:
            - '9200:9200'
            - '9300:9300'
        networks:
            - elk
    Logstash:
        image: logstash:8.5.3
        container_name: logstash
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./logstash/logstash.conf:/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf:ro
        command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
        depends_on:
            - Elasticsearch
        ports:
            - '9600:9600'
        environment:
            LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx750m -Xms750m"    
        networks:
            - elk
    Kibana:
        image: kibana:8.5.3
        container_name: kibana
        restart: always       
        ports:
            - '5601:5601'
        environment:
            - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
        depends_on:
            - Elasticsearch  
        networks:
            - elk
    Filebeat:
        container_name: filebeat
        image: "docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.5.3"
        restart: always
        user: root
        volumes:
            - ./filebeat/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro
            - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:ro
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        networks:
            - elk

volumes:
    elastic_data:

networks:
    elk:
        driver: bridge
```

**logstash/logstash.conf**:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch"
        codec => "json"
        index => "logstash-%{indexDay}"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

And finally the **filebeat/filebeat.yml**:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log'

processors:
- add_docker_metadata:
    host: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash:5044"]
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the index patterns you're trying to create ? Going by the configuration, you should have an index created as logstash-09 or something similar. However, the part `%{indexDay}` seems incorrect. Can you try with `"logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"` and see if it creates today's index ?

Comment: @Ayush It did create today's index and I was able to create a data view in Kibana yes! 
Now when I try to add an integration of "Logstash Logs" it still says "No data has been received from this module yet". Is that normal because they're two separate things?
Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK when you don't specify any index setting in your logstash output, you will see the logs under Logstash logs, but in your case I guess it won't.